# Why isn't a dll loading when I open my solution?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a solution (Visual Studio 2008) that contains a couple of products.  One of these products contains a control that was developed by a colleague that requires loading of a dll.  The dll must be loaded when the solution is loaded so that I can view and use the control.  However, I am getting errors in the error window saying the control is not defined.  When I look on another system (Windows XP Pro) that has VS installed and uses this product and dll, it works fine.  However, when I try to load it on my system (Windows 7), I get the errors.

I used Process Explorer on both systems to verify that the dll in question is being loaded.  On the XP system where everything works fine, I can see the dll needed is being loaded from C:\windows\system32.  I have the dll in the same location (c:\windows\system32) on my Windows 7 box.  However, when I load the solution on the Windows 7 box, I can see through Process Explorer that the dll does not load.  I know c:\windows\system32 is in the path and I can see other dlls from windows\system32 have been loaded by the visual studio executable image.  Why wouldn't this dll be loading?  Is there some logging mechanism within VS that will tell me at load time (when I load the project containing the control) why the dll will not load?

Is this a Windows 7 thing?  Should I not be putting a developed dll in windows/system32?

Help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible this is a version issue. Maybe the version you need isn't there. Make sure that the version required by the product is the same version on your dev machine. Check the version on the XP Pro machine against the version on your win 7 machine. With a strongly named assembly (which I assume your product has), the version is part of the description of what it will look for.

Comment: I can't tell from your question if this is a native DLL or a managed one. Are you targeting the .NET Framework? What language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm the only thing i have in mind is if the .dll is 32bits and you are making a 64bits application they could be  incompatible.

Comment: These are all definitely 32 bit.  No 64 bit machines involved.

Answer (score 1):

One handy trick I use all the time to deal with dll loading issues is to turn on fusion logging. With that, loading exceptions will be logged to a file, where you can see what might be missing or where the framework is probing for it.

To turn it on, set the following registry keys:
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\ForceLog registry value to 1 and HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\LogPath registry value to C:\FusionLogs (this path must exist)

More info on it: 
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Nice link. That's a sweet trick. I'm putting that one in my back pocket. ;-P

Comment: BTW, that points sort of to what I was getting at in my comment to him in his question . . . he says it's not loading. My guess is it's not the right version in the system32 directory . . .

Comment: When you say it isn't the "right version in the system32 directory", what do you mean by that?  What isn't the right version and what version are you referring to?